# Translation of method 'string.CompareTo' failed in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Im getting error of Translation of method 'string.CompareTo' failed for my linq query.

Comment: you need same id to be >= than 6 AND different then 6?

Comment: The posted code does not contain the mentioned offender (compareTo). How are you expecting us to be able to help you?

Comment: @aca: You've misread the query. They're looking for stations who are not station 6 and whose name is greater than the name of station 6. (It's an odd bit of logic, but that's what it says)

Comment: New comment due to your edit: please post full lines of code, not just a fragment of a lambda method. How can we troubleshoot an issue if you don't even show an reproducible example?

Comment: @Flater Oh, but how can the name be greater?

Comment: @aca: Don't shoot the messenger, I only translated ;) I suspect SQL allows this for alphabetical ordering but I have never used it (that I can remember)

Comment: To the OP, maybe consider posting the design of your tables, or the part of it that we need

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Added proper code & SQL code

Comment: Note that your Linq "subquery" does not return a single item, so `ToString()` is not going to do what you think it does. You'll have to add a 'Single()' or `Max()` to get a single value (I'm not certain what Linq supports in a subquery)

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework converts your linq query to SQL and it can translate only functions that it supports, apparently `compareTo` is not supported. Try using compare operators like `==`, `=>`, `<` to make it work.